# Bad image trying to use Multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am having problem with expanding my laptop screen to a external monitor using VGA. When i using only the monitor screen or only the laptop screen the image will be fine, but the problem start if i want to use an extended image, one of the screen will display a bad image with a strange color profile and a lot of noise. Stranger still, i can choose witch one will have the bad image, and it does not depend on witch one i choose as primary. i am sure the cable is fine, and the monitor, and the color profile/resolution/frequency settings are correct. Any ideas what is the cause of this and if it can be fixed?

Comment: Does your graphics adapter have true multi monitor support? I understand that some older adapters can only do one or the other (laptop screen or external) but not both. And since you mention VGA, I assume we're talking older hardware?

Could you provide us with the name and model of the graphics adapter, driver (driver manufacturer and version) and perhaps the same for the laptop and external monitor? I'd like to have a look at the graphic card's data sheet.

Comment: the graphic card is the NVIDIA GT218M (NVS 3100M), i have tried using different drivers whit same results ( nvidia-340 version 340.101-0ubuntu0.16.04.1; xserver-xorg-video-nouveau version 1:1.0.12-1build2; nvidia-304 version 304.134-0ubuntu0.16.04.1). i have (waayyyyy) older laptops that can do this with no problem so i am assuming a 'yes' to multi monitor support, not sure tho...

Comment: Yes, it has multi monitor support.http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvs_techspecs.html , http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-210/specifications

Comment: It could be a driver problem. It is mentioned here: "Nvidia 340 and 346 series of drivers are not working for this dual monitor setup ... driver shows a very noisy picture on the second monitor and its 3D acceleration does not work properly either", http://askubuntu.com/questions/524486/dual-monitor-setup-why-does-nvidia-340-prime-only-detect-one-monitor

Answer (score 0):

Set the same resolution and refresh rate on both displays. Should work like this.

Comment: Why does this help?

Comment: There are limitations of the card and of the output method.